# Pygame Background is drawing on the other image

Tags: pygame

I am new to Python and Pygame and I am wondering why The game Window prints the chessboard on top of the pieces so the pieces arent shown. I think if you put the drawing of the background before everything the other parts should be visible but they arent. Can anyone help?

This is the Program I wrote:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
xBp = 0
yBp = 50
countBp = 0
pygame.display.set_caption("epic Chess")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
brett = pygame.image.load("Chessbot/schachbrett.jpg")
imagesB = [pygame.image.load("Chessbot/imagesbR.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bN.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bB.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bK.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bQ.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bB.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bN.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bR.png")]
running = True
def board_setup():
    global xBp,yBp,countBp
    for i in imagesB:
        countBp += 1
        if countBp <=8:
            screen.blit(i,(xBp,yBp))
            xBp +=50

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    board_setup()
    screen.blit(brett, (0, 0))

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: How is that a dupe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You keep calling `board_setupt` in your `while`, you want to do that just once.

Also, draw the background before placing the pieces.

I'd split the script in a 'initial' and 'game-logic' parts

```
import pygame

def board_setup():
    global xBp,yBp,countBp
    for i in imagesB:
        countBp += 1
        if countBp <=8:
            screen.blit(i,(xBp,yBp))
            xBp +=50

# Initial setup
pygame.init()
xBp = 0
yBp = 50
countBp = 0
pygame.display.set_caption("epic Chess")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
brett = pygame.image.load("Chessbot/schachbrett.jpg")
imagesB = [pygame.image.load("Chessbot/imagesbR.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bN.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bB.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bK.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bQ.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bB.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bN.png"),pygame.image.load("Chessbot/images/bR.png")]screen.blit(brett, (0, 0))
board_setup()
running = True
pygame.display.update()

# Game Logic
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Running this gives a chessboard with multiple pieces on top.

Comment: When I do that the screen closes immediatly and not showing the chess board. Is that right?

Comment: Oeps, probably the function failed, I didn't run it. Just did with some more additions, this works fine.

Comment: If you decide to answer a beginners helpdesk question, at least answer it in a helpful way. Your question may provide an answer to the specific problem, but it is not helpful for the further development of the application. If you only draw everything once before the application loop, how are you going to move the pieces on the board? It is very likely that the aim is to move the pieces, but this is only possible if you do the drawing in the application loop.